# Macbook convert Pandora/youtube Stereo to 5.1 (dolby)

Tags: macbook, streaming, audio-streaming, 5.1, dolbydigital

I have a home theater, Projector, macbook Pro and a ROOFULL converter connected.  I am trying to play Music and hear it in all the speakers (5.1).  So far I read about VLC, but I will need to convert specifically from youtube and pandora.

This is how I have everything connected.
MACBOOK is connected with HDMI to ROOFULL.
ROOFULL is connected to projector through HDMI.
ROOFULL is connected to home theather trough IR.

Comment: You won't get surround sound from most internet sources. The best you can do is to use surround processing in your home theatre amplifier.

Comment: @AFH I don't mind the surround, I would like to have music coming out from the 5 speakers instead of only 2.  is it possible?

Comment: My surround amplifier has various surround modes for 2-channel input: I mostly use one labelled "All Channel Stereo".

Comment: The easiest, platform-independent way would be to just use audio output splitter and connect front and back channel together, then, thought one way audio mixer connect center and subwoofer together.

Comment: In Windows there is "Speaker Fill" (http://imgur.com/a/gyzWl) option which does exactly that, but it requires  #try-supported-channel-layouts in chrome://flags enabled in order to work with for example Youtube videos.

Comment: Did you tried: http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/181929-stereo-upmix-speaker-fill-stereo-to-51-how-to-on-a-mac/

Comment: @hex I tried and Jack is not compatible with the latest OSx

Answer (score 0):

the reason you don't get the 5.1 option with your converter is because its not rated for 5.1. see this post here for more answers:

[How to get optical 5.1 surround audio output Retina MacBook Pro from Logic Pro X](https://superuser.com/questions/846234/how-to-get-optical-5-1-surround-audio-output-retina-macbook-pro-from-logic-pro-x)

this is how your audio devices should look like if your converter is working properly:

[image]

AND

Here is the tutorial to get the soundcard working on a MAC: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3622064?tstart=0

Comment: I tried this,  but I a using HDMI, so my connection isn't USB, I only have the option of 8 channels output but still sound on 2 speakers... any advice?

Comment: HDMI to USB? or another sound card :/ Ill look at this issue closely over the weekend.

Comment: which one do I need to buy?

Comment: @jcho360 in the screenshot, and article the guy tries to make a SB X-fi soundcard work. I would assume that one?